# Is this curve well known?

Tags: differential-equations, curves

I consider the curve $c(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that

$\frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2}=-(a\sin t+b)\frac{dy(t)}{dt}$

$\frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2}=(a\sin t+b)\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$

$a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

Is the orbit curve of solution of above equations known?

Comment: What initial conditions?  For example, all lines are solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean by "known" but this system can be solved explicitly, in quadratures of elementary functions. Set $x'=u,\; y'=v,\; g(t)=a\sin t+b$. Then your system becomes
$$u'=-gv,\quad v'=gu.$$
Multiplying the first equation on $u$ and second on $v$ and adding, we obtain
$u'u+v'v=0,$ therefore $u^2+v^2=c$. Then the first equation becomes
$(u')^2=g^2(c-u^2)$, and this is a separable equation, with an explicit integral.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Excuse me for the wide implications of my remarks.
I wanted to know if it had a name or if there was a reference to be cited.

Comment: If this system is interesting for some reasons, perhaps it has a name, but you know better where it comes from.